# How and where to store images and video files for my web application

Tags: java

I am developing a web based blog application wherein images and videos are attached to an article. So I need inputs on how and where to store these files. Performance is the main concern in my application.

Found through some searching, file system is better than database. How to store in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hosting this blog on a Domain name you would need to add these files to the hosting service you are using. My website uses Cpanel for file management. You need to make sure you are storing the images, files, etc. in the correct path so your code can see it. For example if you want your website to have a background image, the HTML needs to have a section where it calls a CSS class like

```
<div class=background>
```

Then in your css file you set the background image to the location in which your image is stored

```
.background {
 background-image: url("desktop/blog/images/your_image.jpg");
 }
```

The code looks in the desktop --> blog folder --> images folder then looks for a file named "your_image.jpg" and serves it.

In you file manager you need to make sure this file is in a folder that the code can pull from said file manager. Add the file to a folder in the filer manager that you can then call in your code. For example "/blog/images/your_image.jpg" The big thing is that you have a blog folder that contains an image folder that contains the image you want to use all in the file manager your hosting provider uses. your css should then look like this

```
.background{
 background-image: url("../blog/images/your_image.jpg");
 }
```

Comment: Helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be, a structure of folders with a folder for each "table" in your database , and inside each folder a set of folders for each type of file to store and store each file with the ID plus a short description as the name of the file like:

Storage/

```
   /Posts

   /Comments
            /comment_12_main_image.png
   /Users
         /ProfilePictures
                         /user_1_profile_picture.png
```

So you can make a direct relation between the db and the file system.